# Hibernate throws Exception deleted object would be re-saved by cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When I try to delete an object, Hibernate throws Exception as I've written below.

Field DocumentMC in Entity ActionEvent has

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

But I read, that if I set an object to null it must be easily deleted. Where is my fault?

Also I use `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`

My code:

```
    if(Objects.nonNull(childActionEvent)) {
        for (ActionEvent event : childActionEvent) {
            event.setoDocumentMC(null);
            actionEventDao.saveOrUpdate(event);
            actionEventDao.deleteByID(event.getId());
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [org.project.models.documents.DocumentMC#10294993]
```

Comment: just delete the event, that will automatically delete the child.

Comment: In debug when I try actionEventDao.deleteByID(event.getId());
it throws Exception, that DocumentMC will be re-saved

Comment: As stated the only thing you should do and **really the only thing** is delete the event. Don't save, don't set stuff to null, just delete.

Comment: If you have a bidrectional onetoone relationship, make sure to also set the event field to null